# Why is Web Essentials 'Create Javascript/Typescript Intellisense file' disabled?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-essentials

In Visual Studio 2015, I can see the menu item under the context menu to create a Javascript or Typescript intellisense file, but it's disabled.

What do I have to do to enable this?

Comment: Able to do what? You're just asking why it's greyed out but failing to explain what you're trying to do so the question is slightly unclear.

Comment: I am wondering why it's grayed out, and what needs to happen for it to be available

Comment: same problem here....